# Python re.search finds result but group doesnt work

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to find number matching my pattern inside every line in the .txt file.
**text fragment**

```
sometext - 0.007442749125388171
sometext - 0.004296183916209439
sometext - 0.0037923667088698393
sometext - 0.003137404884873018
```

**code**

```py
file = codecs.open(FILEPATH, encoding='utf-8')
for cnt, line in enumerate(file):
    result_text = re.match(r'[a-zżźćńółęąś]*', line).group()
    result_value = re.search(r'[0-9].[0-9]*', line).group()
    print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line))
```

It's strange because re.search finds results:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 28), match='0.001879612135574806'>
```

but if I want to assign result to variable I get this:
**error**

```
File "read.py", line 18, in <module>
result_value = re.search(r'[0-9].[0-9]*', line).group()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your file so we can reproduce?

Comment: yeah, check now

Comment: Your code is a bit brittle right now and depends on there being a match. Are you checking that each line actually has a match group before trying to call `.group()` on it?

Comment: If your file structure is this, you can use `split()` command. no need to use regex.
Example :- 
for data in file.readline():
          txt, val = data.split('-')[0] , data.split('-')[1]
          print("Line {} : {}".format(txt, val))

Answer (score 2):

When capturing a group in a regular expression, you need to put parentheses around the group that you aim to capture. Also, you need to pass the index of the group you want to capture to the `group()` method.

For example, for your second match, the code should be modified as follows:

```
# There is only 1 group here, so we pass index 1
result_value = re.search(r'([0-9].[0-9]*)', line).group(1)
```

As proposed by other comments in your question, you may also want to check whether matches were found before trying to extract the captured groups:

```
import re

with open("file.txt") as text_file:
    for i, line in enumerate(text_file):
        text_matches = re.match(r'([a-zżźćńółęąś]*)', line)
        if text_matches is None:
            continue

        text_result = text_matches.group(1)

        value_matches = re.search(r'([0-9].[0-9]*)', line)
        if value_matches is None:
            continue

        value_result = value_matches.group(1)

        print("Line {}: {}".format(text_result, value_result))
```

Comment: still the same error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: The full code sample I posted above runs. Can you verify that the checks are present, as well as the parentheses in the regex?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest a tighter regex definition:

```
^([a-zżźćńółęąś]+)\s+-\s+(\d+\.\d+)$
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/UCk6d7/1)

**Explanation**

- multiline mode: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of the string)
- `^` assert the beginning of the line
- ([a-zżźćńółęąś]+) capture group to match the "identifier"
- `\s+-\s+` the separator in-between with a variable number of spaces
- `(\d+\.\d+)` matches the decimal number
- `$` asserts the end of the line

[Sample Code](https://ideone.com/S6WWaO):

```
import re
regex = r"^([a-zżźćńółęąś]+)\s+-\s+(\d+\.\d+)$"
test_str = ("sometext - 0.007442749125388171\n"
    "sometext - 0.004296183916209439\n"
    "sometext - 0.0037923667088698393\n"
    "sometext - 0.003137404884873018")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for match in matches:
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        print ("Group {groupNum}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, group = match.group(groupNum)))
```